# SSRS Color Expression Lesser than X

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table that handles stock, I have the data outputting in to a table in SSRS so I can see stock levels. like so:

```
PartNumber, PartDescription, Qty
```

I can use

```
 =IIF (Fields!Qty.Value < 40, "red", "teal")
```

on the quantity field to set a threshold within the table but it applies this to every row.

Is there a way to set unique thresholds per row (PartNumber)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a threshold for every `PartNumber` you can store it in your `ReportDataSource`.

For example: `PartNumber`, `Threshold`, `PartDescription`, `Qty`

Then change expression in:

```
=IIf(Fields!Qty.Value < Fields!Threshold.Value, "Color1", "Color2")
```